# ASP.NET Listbox not changing index

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, listbox

My question is probably a simple one to people used to ASP.NET, So here it is:
I have a webform in a master page that has a listbox which populates itself with numbers which serve as unique id for my objects.

The only problem is that the selected index property of the listbox is always -1 and it automatically deselects itself, no matter what I select. I understand that the index is -1 when you havent selected anyhting, but I have. Here is my C# code that I used to test it and my ASP.NET code:

```
protected void List_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(List.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(List.Items[2].ToString());
}
```

I use the first message box to see what the selected index is and the second to check my 3rd items in the listbox is being recognised.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="List" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
        EnableViewState="true" 
        onselectedindexchanged="List_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: messagebox.show? are you sure this an asp.net web forms application, and not a winforms application?

Comment: its an asp.net web forms application but I've been using messagebox's to test what variables equal at certain points in the application.

Comment: Do you enable an auto post back property of list box?Tell us how data fill into list box and where do you put a code to fill a list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you Databind your Listbox on every Postback in Page.Load?